# Find kth largest element in the union of two sorted array

Tags: c#, algorithm, programming-challenge, binary-search

Problem statement:
Find \$kth\$ largest element in the union of two sorted array.

**My introduction of the algorithm**
I spent a few hours to review two algorithms, [Leetcode 4:Median of Two Sorted Arrays](https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/) and [Leetcode 215:Kth Largest Element in an Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-largest-element-in-an-array/) together since median is a special case of kth element problem, and also read [the article](http://articles.leetcode.com/find-k-th-smallest-element-in-union-of) to talk about the kth largest element in the union of two sorted array, 3 solutions: 1:The trivial way, \$O(m+n)\$; 2: A better way, O(k); 3: The best solution, but non-trivial, O(lg m + lg n).

So, I decided to practice the algorithm "Find kth largest element in the union of two sorted array" (similar to Leetcode 4 and 215, but with some difference.), using binary search non-trivial one, [C# Source code](https://gist.github.com/jianminchen/dda5a982c62fbe108ea1e3ce706261f4). Please help me to review the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KthLargestElementTwoSortedArrays_OptimalSolution
{
    /*
     * Problem statement:
     * Find kth largest element in the union of two sorted array.
     * 
     * Introduction:
     * 
     * Review Leetcode 4 and Leetcode 215 two algorithm, and then, read the  article: 
     * http://articles.leetcode.com/find-k-th-smallest-element-in-union-of
     *   
     *    
     * 
     * Introduction of algorithms for the solutions:
     * There are a few of solutions to solve the problem, one is to merge two sorted array and then
     * find the kth largest element, the solution will take O(m + n) time, where m and n are two arrays's 
     * length respectively. 
     * 
     * But, we do not stop here. Try to beat the solution in time complexity, the following solution
     * use binary search, and then use recursive solution to solve a small subproblem. 
     * 
     * We do not need to sort first k element in the array, and then find kth element. As long as 
     * we know that less than k/2 elements (denoted as m) are smaller than kth element in two sorted 
     * array, then we can solve a small subproblem - find (k - m)th largest element in two sorted 
     * array instead. 
     *        
     * 
     */
     class KthLargestElement
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           RunSampleTestcase1();
        }

        /*
         * 5th largest element from a union of two sorted arrays, integers from 1 to 10.          
         */
        public static void RunSampleTestcase1()
        {
           int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
           int[] array2 = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };

           Debug.Assert( FindKthLargestElement(array1, array2, 5) == 5);
        }

        public static double FindKthLargestElement(int[] array1, int[] array2, int k)
        {
           return FindKthLargestElement_BinarySearch(array1, array1.Length, array2, array2.Length, k);
        }

        /*
         *
         * Using binary search to find kth largest element from the union of two sorted array 
         * in time complexity O(lg(n + m))
         *
         * Naive solution is to merge two sorted array, and then find kth largest element. 
         * Time complexity is O(n + m), n, m are the length of two arrays respectively. 
         *    
         * Current solution is to use binary search to expedite the search. 
         * 
         * Function spec: 
         *
         * Find kth largest element from two sorted arrays, 
         * @array1 - sorted array ascending order
         * @array2 - soretd array ascending order
         * 
         * Always try to remove k/2 elements one time
         * 
         * Recursive function: subproblem is a smaller problem. 
         */
         private static double FindKthLargestElement_BinarySearch(
            int[] array1,
            int   length1,
            int[] array2,
            int   length2,
            int   k)
        {
            //always assume that length1 is equal or smaller than length2
            if (length1 > length2)
                return FindKthLargestElement_BinarySearch(array2, length2, array1, length1, k);

            if (length1 == 0)
               return array2[k - 1];

            if (k == 1)
                return Math.Min(array1[0], array2[0]);

            //divide k into two parts  
            int half_k         = Math.Min(k / 2, length1); 
            int rest_kElements = k - half_k;

            if (array1[half_k - 1] == array2[rest_kElements - 1])
               return array1[half_k - 1];

            if (array1[half_k - 1] < array2[rest_kElements - 1])
            {
               // kth largest element definitely not in the range of array1[i], i is in [0, middleOfSearch_1 - 1]
               int[] newArray1 = ArraySplice(array1, half_k);
               return FindKthLargestElement_BinarySearch(newArray1, length1 - half_k, array2, length2, k - half_k);
            }
            else
            {
               int[] newArray2 = ArraySplice(array2, rest_kElements);
               return FindKthLargestElement_BinarySearch(array1, length1, newArray2, length2 - rest_kElements, k - rest_kElements);
            }
        }

        /*
        * Remove first n items from the array
        * 
        * similar to JavaScript array's API: splice
        *    https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice
        * 
        * syntax
        * array.splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, ...)
        * 
        */
        public static int[] ArraySplice(int[] array, int deleteCount)
        {
           int length = array.Length;

           if (deleteCount <= length)
           {
               int[] result = new int[length - deleteCount];
               for (int i = 0; i < length - deleteCount; i++)
                   result[i] = array[deleteCount + i];

               return result;
           }

           return new int[] { };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty minor but not pass length to FindKthLargestElement_BinarySearch

Comment: @Paparazzi, I like your advice. Can you explain it with more detail, you suggest that it is better to set a class member as length variable?

Comment: Just get the length directly from the array

Comment: @Paparazzi, that is a very good advice, so the function FindKthLargestElement_BinarySearch has 3 arguments instead of 5.

Comment: Sure seems to me you could do this with interval half in O(sqrt(k))

Comment: @Paparazzi, can you explain your idea of O(sqrt(k))? I have some interesting to know your thoughts on this compared to O(log(n+m)).

Comment: Look up bisection method

Comment: Just so you know, your solution appears to be \$O(\log k * (n+m))\$.  The reason is that `ArraySplice()` makes a copy of the array, which takes either \$O(n)\$ or \$O(m)\$ time.  If you would just avoid doing the copy and instead pass a starting index for each array to your function, you would be down to \$O(\log k)\$ time.

Comment: @JS1, you are correct on time complexity concern about `ArraySplice()`, it brings extra maximum \$O(n+m)\$ copy each time. Passing a starting index instead will work.

Comment: @JS1, I wrote a new version of C# code, passing a starting index instead of using ArraySplice(), the code link is https://gist.github.com/jianminchen/70e896b5fed50a9a0b50f81dfba28497

Comment: @JianminChen The new version looks good.

Comment: @JS1, I am planing to post a question on the code as well today. Please help me review my new question called Leetcode 49: group anagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't comment yet, so a few clarifications:

1. Isn't your test `RunSampleTestcase1()` incorrect? The fifth largest value would be 6. You appear to be returning the 5th *smallest* value. Also evidenced by `return Math.Min(array1[0], array2[0]);`. I'd think the k^th largest should be `return Math.Max(array1[array1.Length - 1], array2[array2.Length - 1])`.
2. Why are you passing length as a parameter to `FindKthLargestElement_BinarySearch()`? Arrays already have a length parameter. Using that will make the code much easier to follow.
3. Why are you reinventing the wheel with `ArraySplice()`?

---

Note: All of these have one big red flag though. That article you linked is referencing arrays; however, it discusses using linked lists in the Big O notation. Those have a lot different properties than arrays in C#.

Comment: @C Smith, you are correct, my code is to work on kth smallest element instead; however, in order to calculate largest element, just calculate (n + m - k) smallest element.

Comment: @C Smith, you are correct that the array's length does not need to be passed as an argument in the function FindKthLargestElement_BinarySearch.

Comment: @C Smith, ArraySplice() function, I did check C# Array class and found that the documentation of the array Splice API is not so clear as JavaScript array does.

Comment: @C Smith, I am not sure your note about the article, reference arrays vs linked list, Big O notation. Can you help me more on this concern?

Comment: @jianmin, the issue with the big o notation is that the author was only considering starting at the beginning of a list, and then working towards the end. This ignores known elements about an array (such as length), which can absolutely speed this up. Additionally, you don't need to do a binary search. In fact, you're probably able to speed this up to O(ln(k)). But I'll leave the proof up to you. As a starting point, consider finding where arr1 and arr2 intersect on the last element.

Comment: @C Smith, thank you to let me know O(ln(k)) solution out there. I knew that when k is close to m+n, O(ln(k)) is same as O(ln(m+n)). I will catch up more after this practice.